# No Repeat Random Image

Tags: android

I have a random image displayer. But sometimes it shows same images. I want to display 1 image only once...

```
                TypedArray ar = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.arabalar);
            int len = ar.length();
            int[] resIds = new int[len];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                resIds[i] = ar.getResourceId(i, 0);
            ar.recycle();

            Random rand = new Random();
            int rndInt = rand.nextInt(resIds.length) + 1;
            try {
                int resID = resIds[rndInt];
                ImageView logolar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logolar);
                logolar.setImageResource(resID);
                lastImageName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(resID); //String lastImageName = getResources().getResourceName(resID); // bu da kullanilabilir
                TextView logoismi = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.logoismi);
                logoismi.setText(previousImageName);
                clickeddata.add(logoismi.getText().toString()); //bir onceki logo verilerini depolama ozelligi
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            previousImageName = lastImageName;
```

Comment: You just need to track the Random Int values. You could do something like create a List<Integer> or a HashSet<Integer> check if the list/set contains the next Random Int obtained, if not, add it to the list, and display the image, if it does, keep looping for a Random Int that hasn't yet been used.  You could also check the size of the list/set if it reaches the size of the array then you know all images have been displayed once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shuffle the resource id array and use it as the backing list.

```
        private int[] resIds;

        private int index;
```

Do this once at the start:

```
        TypedArray ar = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.arabalar);
        int len = ar.length();
        resIds = new int[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            resIds[i] = ar.getResourceId(i, 0);
        ar.recycle();

        // shuffle
        // loop backwards through the array and swap each item 
        // with a random item from the values below it
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = resIds.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
            // swap
            int temp = resIds[i];
            resIds[i] = resIds[index];
            resIds[index] = temp;
        }
```

Now just step through your array:

```
        try {
            int resID = resIds[index];
            ImageView logolar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logolar);
            logolar.setImageResource(resID);
            lastImageName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(resID); //String lastImageName = getResources().getResourceName(resID); // bu da kullanilabilir
            TextView logoismi = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.logoismi);
            logoismi.setText(previousImageName);
            clickeddata.add(logoismi.getText().toString()); //bir onceki logo verilerini depolama ozelligi
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        previousImageName = lastImageName;
        index++;
```

Comment: Oops, forgot a line `Random random = new Random();` updated answer.

Comment: Post your code that changes to the next image, button click, swipe, etc.  If the image is in an adapter item view then post your adapter code.

Comment: I take images in only array there are no codes extra?